# How do I pass additional parameters to a native android plugin in NativeScript?

Tags: java, android, nativescript

I'm writing a small native android plugin for my NativeScript application, but then there's a part where I have to pass several string parameters into the java code and that is surprisingly problematic. It turns out that when I attempt to call a method that requires anything else by the android context, the call fails.

Here's my JS that calls the method:

```
var application = require("application");
var context = application.android.context;

module.exports = {
    startService: function(serviceName) {
        var serviceInitializer = new service.fi.geolocationpollingservice.ServiceInitializer();
        serviceInitializer.startService(context, serviceName, userToken, locationUrl);
    }
};
```

and here's the actual java method:

```
public class ServiceInitializer {

    public void startService(Context context, String serviceName, String userToken, String backendUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "serviceName: " + serviceName + "; userToken: " + userToken + "; backendUrl: " + backendUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure that serviceName, userToken and locationUrl are initialized with appropriate string values, but when I attempt to execute that method from my application, I get the following error :

```
Unhandled Exception
com.tns.nativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreateView 

Reference Error: userToken is not defined
File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.forni/files/app/tns_modules/geo-polling-service-plugin/index.js, line 7, column 62"
```

Comment: The error message is verbose enough - you have missing variables in your javascript, the "additional parameters" is not the problem at hand.

Comment: true... the original version of my code had a different error, but then I started experimenting with it and forgot to revert everything before posting it here, but now it's too late to remove the question...

Answer (score 1):

If you code is exactly as shown above then the error message is spot on; I don't see a JS variable declared named `userToken`.

Comment: I was experimenting once I got my original problem and the I forgot to revert all of my experiment changes... this question with this error is in fact irrelevant, but now I don't know hot to remove it...